# Changing the order of struct members when debugging in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am trying to align some data in a c# struct that was created in c++. I know I'm a couple of bytes off, but I can't tell where becuase VS organizes the members in alphabetical order, rather than the order the occur in the struct (which is defined explicitly).

Is it possible to change the order of the display of members in the debug dialog that shows the struct's values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use a clever [`DebuggerDisplay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx) attribute for your struct.

Comment: I found what I needed without having to use this, but it looks like a neat technique!

Answer (score 0):

Open up your binary in cdb (from the Debugging Tools for Windows) via this command:

```
cdb -z \path\to\your\yourlibrary.dll
```

then run

```
dt yourlibrary!NameOfYourStruct
```

This will tell you exactly how the structure is laid out.